# Checking server status - online/offline

Tags: php, ip-address, server

I have a loop showing info of many different servers from database.
Now i am trying to write if they are online or offline.
I have tried to write manually the ip address and port to the srcipt and it works fine. However when i tried to put the table into the variable it shows that all are offline. Most of them use 44405 port so i put it manually for now to check it.

EDIT: yes i know that this mysql code is ready and waiting for injection :D

```
<?php //-----loading servers to website-----
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors','1');

$connection = //deleted this part coz includes personal info :D


$alldata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM muonline ORDER BY id DESC;");
while ($loadservers = mysql_fetch_assoc($alldata)) {


echo "<tr>";

  echo '<td>';  //-----here starts the online/offline part of script-----

    $serwer = $loadservers['serverAddress'];
    $port="44405";
    $socket=@fsockopen($serwer,$port,$errno,$errstr,2);

    if($socket==true)
    {
     echo "<p>online</p>";
    }else{
     echo "<p>offline</p>";
    }
    echo '</td>';

//------- here is being loaded rest of info of the each server-----
echo "<td><p>" .$loadservers['serverName']."</p></td>";
echo "<td><p>". '<a href="' .$loadservers['serverAddress'].'"target="_blank"><p>'.$loadservers['serverAddress']. "</p></a>". "</td>";
echo "<td><p>" .$loadservers['serverExp']. "</p></td>";
echo "<td><p>" .$loadservers['serverDrop']. "</p></td>";
echo "<td><p>" .$loadservers['info']. "</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Echo the value of `$serwer` - double check its what you expect.

Comment: Also, remove the @ in front of `fsockopen` - it'll suppress any error messages you're getting here.

Comment: Thank you for a great tip. I echoed it and website shows me addresses of particular servers like http://www.... so its exactly what i wanted and seems correct

Comment: @Bulk Thank you, i just did that, but nothing changes :(
I dont know if i can post it here but here is my website: http://mutoplist.com/

Comment: Do the servers all start with http://? I'm fairly sure `fsockopen` only works with just the server names.

Comment: Yes, it is required on my website to add the addres in form starting from http

Comment: That's not going to work then. You need to extract the server/host from the URL using `parse_url`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Wow, without http it works great. Thank you so much! Give it as answer, i will give you ++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to use `fsockopen` with a server starting with `http://`. You'll need to parse the URL using `parse_url`, extract the `host` part of the URL and check using that. Like this:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($loadservers['serverAddress']);
$socket = fsockopen($parsedUrl['host'],$port,$errno,$errstr,2);
```

Comment: Vote up requires more reputation, ill do that as fast as possible :D